# Visa for a layover of 13 hrs at Bangkok airport

Tags: visas, transit, bangkok

I am travelling to Sydney from India by Thai airways in the first week of June and have a layover of 13 hrs at Bangkok airport. I would like to explore the city and wanted to know which visa should I opt for; Visa on arrival which costs 2000 Bahts or is there any other visa?

TIA

Comment: Passport? Indian?

Comment: The visa on arrival fee has been waived until 31 October 2019 https://www.thailand-business-news.com/tourism/72319-thailand-extends-free-visa-on-arrival-until-31-october-2019.html

Comment: @Mark Mayo Yes Indian passport, sorry for missing out on it.

Comment: @hojusaram Thank you very much for the share

Comment: @hojusaram put as an answer perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Indian citizens can use Visa on Arrival for a stay of up to 15 days. The fee for this visa is 2000 THB and must be paid in local currency. Sometimes there is a long queue, and there is a fast track option for an additional fee of 200 THB.

At the time of writing, the visa on arrival fee has been [waived](https://www.thai.lt/blog/870-extension-of-thailand-visa-on-arrival-fees-waiver-2019)

> Visa on Arrival fee waiver was first implemented from 15 November 2018
>   to 13 January 2019. Later, the period of Visa on Arrival fee exemption
>   was extended from 14 January 2019 to 30 April 2019. As the time of
>   this visa fee waiver is coming to the end, the Cabinet just announced
>   that Thailand Visa on Arrival fee exemption will be extended for 6
>   more months - until 31 October 2019